OOP command design pattern with polymorphism
I'm trying to make a command-like interface for a user system using OOP design structure and principles.
So I have an abstract User class and different types of users that derive from it.
Then I have CommandInterface class [takes input strings (user input splitted to strings in main? (stringstream)] which holds a pointer to the loggedInUser of type base class (User * loggedInUser) and has commands:

login [name] // makes the interface be "logged" as this user
signup [name] [age] [pass] etc. // Adds a User to the system itself (a different class)
exit // Logs out if logged in, or shuts down the interface if not

While logged in you also have access to the commands (methods) of the different types of users. So lets say User has a method print() that prints out all the user data.
User1 : User has method a();
User2: User has method b();
Now how can I call the different methods of the different users while only having a pointer of type User (base class)?
Code (c++/pseudo):
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class CommandInterface {
  static unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Command>>> interfaceCommands = {...};
  std::shared_ptr<User> loggedUser = nullptr;
  
  // Singleton
  static CommandInterface* instance;
  CommandInterface() = default;
  std::unique_ptr<System> sys = System::getInstance(); // Instance to system which holds users (also singleton)

public:
  // Singleton
  CommandInterface(const CommandInterface& other) = delete;
  CommandInterface(CommandInterface&& other) = default;
  CommandInterface& operator=(const CommandInterface& other) = delete;
  CommandInterface& operator=(CommandInterface&& other) = default;
  ~CommandInterface() = default;
  static CommandInterface* getInstance();

  

  // Commands
  void signup(const std::string& name, uint8_t age, std::string& userType); // Adds users to System
  
  void login(const std::string& name) {
    if(loggedUser) {
      throw std::exception();
    }
    else {
      loggedUser = sys->getUser(name);
    }
  }
  
  void exitCmd() {
    if(loggedUser) {
      loggedUser = nullptr;
    }
    else {
      // Will be caught so that all the destructors are called
      // Since std::exit(0) won't call the destructors
      throw std::runtime_error("Exit.");
    }
  }
  
  
  std::shared_ptr<User> &getLoggedUser(); // Getter, used by the commands
  
  void executeCommand(const std::string& command, const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
    if(!loggedUser) {
      // Throw exception if command doesn't exist
      interfaceCommands[command]->execute(args);
    }
    else {
      // Throw exception if command doesn't exist (different users also hold static map of their commands to check)
      loggedUser->getCommand(name)->execute(args); // Some pure virtual method
    }
  }
};


class Command {
public:
  virtual ~Command() = default;
  virtual void execute(const std::vector<std::string>& args) const = 0;
};

class PrintCMD : public Command {
public:
  void execute(const std::vector<std::string>& args) const override {
    CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser()->print();
  }
};

class ACMD : public Command {
public:
  void execute(const std::vector<std::string>& args) const override {
    CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser()->a(); // Error Here
  }
};

class BCMD : public Command {
public:
  void execute(const std::vector<std::string>& args) const override {
    CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser()->b(); // Error Here
  }
};

The code shows a sample implementation and 2 errors occur in the classes ACMD and BCMD, because no such methods are found.
So the problem is how to deal with the polymorphism that "shadows" the derived classes' methods?

This is a lot of code for a fairly straightforward question. Can you try to write a minimal reproducible example, with emphasis on "minimal"?

[tag:command-line]? I don't see how it's revenant here.

Who instantiates ACMD? Who calls execute on it? How do they know that the current user has method a()? Or alternatively, if ACMD is instantiated and executed unconditionally, what should happen if the current user doesn't in fact have method a()?

loggedUser->getCommand(name)->execute(args) Why not simply loggedUser->execute(name, args)? The intermediate getCommand appears to serve no purpose, as the command just turns around calls right back into the user. This way, the user with method a() could recognize command "a". It's unclear why you even want Command class, what purpose it's supposed to serve.

Or, since apparently it's the responsibility of User-derived class to manufacture ACMD in the first place, that class could just pass its own this pointer to the command, and have the command call a() on this pointer (of type User1*) rather than CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser()

Can't fix pseudocode. Pseudocode is always valid, by definition. There are no rules to follow!

All that u need is declare virtual method in base class. For example:
class User:
{
   virtual void execute(const std:vector<std::strings>& args) = 0;
}

And now, having Base-Type pointer to child, you could allocate to child overrided virtual method.
About an error:

CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser()->b();

Try to use brackets
(CommandInterface::getInstance()->getLoggedUser())->b(); 

And also make sure that these User methods are public.
